# Find most used words in post titles

Tags: posts, functions

Is there any technical way to search post titles and return the results of the most used duplicated words in them?

I.e
Three articles in total:

- The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
- A brown bag for the summer
- New record - Athlete jumps higher

Most used words in post titles:

1. Brown
2. Jumps

Comment: Yes - there is always a way.  There is no built-in method, however, if that is what you are asking.  It would require many lines of custom code to A: build an array of post titles; B: parse individual words from each; C: sort by frequency.  Post a new question when you get stuck on a specific step.

Answer (score 0):

Below MYSQL query return the 10 most common value (words) in a post_title(column) FROM wp_posts(table):

```
SELECT post_title, COUNT(post_title) AS Appearances FROM wp_posts GROUP BY post_title ORDER BY Appearances DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This will only count duplicated titles, not the words inside them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a custom (and ugly) SQL query, here is something that might interest you.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wp_posts.post_title, ' ', words.n), ' ', -1) word, count(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wp_posts.post_title, ' ', words.n), ' ', -1)) count

FROM (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10) words

INNER JOIN wp_posts on CHAR_LENGTH(wp_posts.post_title) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(wp_posts.post_title, ' ', '')) >= words.n - 1

WHERE wp_posts.post_type != 'revision' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wp_posts.post_title, ' ', words.n), ' ', -1) NOT IN ('-', '&', ',', '.')
  AND LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wp_posts.post_title, ' ', words.n), ' ', -1)) > 3

GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count DESC, word ASC;
```

Explanation:

This query fetch all the `post_title` from the table and split them in words so we can group and count them individually.

It filters the rows when the post is not a revision and is published.
It can also exclude some words from the results (with the `NOT IN` clause).
It can also exclude small words (with the `LENGTH > 3` clause).

NOTE : If your titles have more than 10 words, they will not be counted properly. You will have to adapt the `select 1 n union all...` line to count more words.

The query is widely adapted from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/2342137

PS : If anyone wants to rewrite the SQL if it is possible to reuse the `word` column instead of doing the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` multiple times, that would be great.